# Remove unwanted paths from the file tree in Java

Tags: java

I have implemented something like this

```
public class s {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String rootDir = ".";
        String componentName="IAS/";
        String environmentName = "FAT/";
        String branchName = "FAT-TCP-IAS/";
        String instanceName = "IAS-jer-1";

        File folder = new File(rootDir + componentName);

        File source = new File(folder.toString());
        List<File> filesList = (List<File>) FileUtils.listFiles(source, TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE, TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE);
        for (File file : filesList) {
            // work on the files
                System.out.println(file);
        }
    }

    }
```

The result of this method is:

```
/IAS/default/1.3/pennytunnelservice.properties
/IAS/default/1.3/gateway.properties
/IAS/DEV/gateway.properties
/IAS/FAT/pennytunnelservice.properties
/IAS/FAT/FAT-TCP-IAS/IAS-jer-1/gateway.properties
/IAS/FAT/FAT-TCP-IAS/IAS-jer-1/version@1.5
/IAS/FAT/FAT-TCP-IAS/gateway.properties
/IAS/FAT/FAT-TCP-IAS/IAS-jer-2/version@1.9
/IAS/FAT/FAT-TCP-IAS/IAS-jer-2/gateway.properties
/IAS/FAT/FAT-SSL-IAS/gateway.properties
/IAS/FAT/gateway.properties
```

I would like to have result where will be only paths which are not mentioned in variables. So my expected result should be:

```
/IAS/default/1.3/pennytunnelservice.properties
/IAS/default/1.3/gateway.properties
/IAS/FAT/pennytunnelservice.properties
/IAS/FAT/FAT-TCP-IAS/IAS-jer-1/gateway.properties
/IAS/FAT/FAT-TCP-IAS/IAS-jer-1/version@1.5
/IAS/FAT/FAT-TCP-IAS/gateway.properties
/IAS/FAT/gateway.properties
```

There are only paths with strings:

```
String componentName="IAS/";
String environmentName = "FAT/";
String branchName = "FAT-TCP-IAS/";
String instanceName = "IAS-jer-1";
```

Do you have some hint for me please?

Comment: You never use these variables in the parsing, why expecting something else? Use some kind of filter somewhere.

Comment: I tried to add condition if (file.getPath().contains(componentName) || ...) etc. but this did not work.

Comment: Show us the code that failed, don't call for a solution.

Comment: `file.getPath().contains(componentName)` will be true for all the paths you listed there.

Comment: @Zachary I know, but have no idea what to change.

Comment: You will need uniquely filter the files you want filtered. as `IAS/` is the prefix for all paths, you can't use that String with `String.contains` as it will return true for all paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to exclude certain directories from the directory print out, you will need to loop through the parent directories of a path and check if none of the paths are in the list of excluded paths.

For example: if you want to exclude this from the output:

```
/IAS/DEV/gateway.properties
```

You will need to loop through the parent paths:

1. DEV
2. IAS

And see if none of them are in the excluded list. If for example DEV is in the excluded list, then you exclude this file from the output.

You could use code similar to the following sample below to achieve this exclusion behaviour. Here we are using Java 7 `java.nio.file` classes to loop through the path of a file (`file.getParent().spliterator()` is used for this purpose).

```
List<String> exclusionPaths = Arrays.asList("elastic54", "elastic56", "elastic57", "elastic60");
Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get("d:/work/eclipse"), new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
        boolean printOut = StreamSupport.stream(file.getParent().spliterator(), false)
                .noneMatch(path -> exclusionPaths.stream().anyMatch(s -> path.toString().equals(s)));
        if (attrs.isDirectory() || !printOut) {
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
        System.out.println(file);
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }
});
```

An advantage of this code is that you need no external libraries to recursive traverse directories. All libraries used here are in JDK 8.

**Update**

If you want to mention only inclusion paths - reversing the logic described above -, you can change the above code minimally to achieve that:

```
List<String> inclusionPaths = Arrays.asList("elastic54", "elastic56", "elastic57", "elastic60");
Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get("d:/work/eclipse"), new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
        boolean printOut = StreamSupport.stream(file.getParent().spliterator(), false)
                .anyMatch(path -> inclusionPaths.stream().anyMatch(s -> path.toString().equals(s)));
        if (attrs.isDirectory() || !printOut) {
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
        System.out.println(file);
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }
});
```

You just need to change the `"noneMatch"` method to `"anyMatch"`.

Comment: That's pretty nice, but I have problem how to find exclusionPaths in directory structure. I only know paths which wanted to no exclude such as "IAS", "FAT" etc.

Comment: @sipekmichal.cz Please check the updated answer. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: unfortunately this is not what I am looking for. I would like to get the result such as give me your example before update, but I don't know exclusionPaths.

Answer (score 0):

You have to match each `file`'s path with your list.
However you'll have to rethink of these strings, as they don't make sense with the example you gave.

```
List<String> alreadymentioned = Arrays.asList("IAS/", "FAT/", "FAT-TCP-IAS/", "IAS-jer-1");

String regex = "";
for(String each : alreadymentioned)
    regex += each.replaceAll("\\/", "\\\\/") + "|";
regex = regex.substring(0, regex.length()-1);
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

File folder = new File(rootDir + componentName);

File source = new File(folder.toString());
List<File> filesList = (List<File>) FileUtils.listFiles(source, TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE, TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE);
for (File file : filesList) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(file.getAbsolutePath());
    // work on the files
    if(!matcher.find())
        System.out.println(file);
}
```

Thank you, @XtremeBaumer!

Comment: this wont work, because you check if a string array contains a file. what would work is to check if the file-path contains any of the strings in the array